# Auto Click Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot call & click a button using their ClassName or ID. I get an error

> .click is not a function

What is wrong in my code?

I want to autoclick  the download button using their ClassName or ID and tried the two code below but it is not working.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("toolbar_download_button").click();
});
```

```html
<div id="toolbarNew" class="toolbar">
  <div id="toolbarContainer">
    <div id="toolbarViewer">
      <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
        <button id="toolbar_download_button" type="button" class="toolbarButton" style="float: left;" data-cha-target-name="download_doc_btn" data-cha-location="doc_viewer" data-cha-action-type="download" data-cha-action-target-id="50272799" data-testid="toolbar-download-btn">
             <div class="toolbarButton_tooltip" data-testid="toolbar-download-btn-tooltip">Download</div></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector(".toolbarButton")` or  
`document.getElementById("toolbar_download_button")` if you want to use the ID

Comment: You will then likely fail for security reasons anyway.

Comment: yeah i think you are right because of the security reason i cant automate the click it is a Coursehero.com automatic clicking the button download

Comment: do you have any suggestion or anyway to click the button ? https://ibb.co/KwDWz2X

Comment: you can use jquery  $("#toolbar_download_button").trigger("click");

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up the jQuery click handler with Vanilla JavaScript. That's why it's throwing the error you mentioned.

If you want to add a click event handler you could do in several ways:

- With the native [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) event handler
- With the native [`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) global event handler
- With jQuery's [`click`](https://api.jquery.com/click/)
- With jQuery's [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler)

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  // Vanilla JavaScript 'click'
  document.getElementById("toolbar_download_button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log("Fire one");
  });

  // Vanilla JavaScript 'onclick'
  document.getElementById("toolbar_download_button").onclick = function() {
    console.log("Fire two");
  };

  // With jQuery's 'click'
  $("#toolbar_download_button").click(function() {
    console.log("Fire three");
  });
  
  // With jQuery's 'on'
  $("#toolbar_download_button").on('click', function() {
    console.log("Fire four");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="toolbarNew" class="toolbar">
  <div id="toolbarContainer">
    <div id="toolbarViewer">
      <div id="toolbarViewerRight">
        <button id="toolbar_download_button" type="button" class="toolbarButton" style="float: left;" data-cha-target-name="download_doc_btn" data-cha-location="doc_viewer" data-cha-action-type="download" data-cha-action-target-id="50272799" data-testid="toolbar-download-btn">
             <div class="toolbarButton_tooltip" data-testid="toolbar-download-btn-tooltip">Download</div></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tip: If decide to add [jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) to your project, then you might as well take advantage of it and use it to handle everything (capturing DOM elements, adding event handlers, etc.,). Otherwise use the native JavaScript handlers instead.